# Set Target Audience by specific view in SharePoint List using Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, audience-targeting

In Classic Experience, there's an "Edit Page" on settings where I can access and set target audience per specific view of SharePoint List, however, this is not possible on Modern Experience.

Are there any ways where I can restrict those so other group user cannot open specific views?

Comment: Are you using communication site or team site?

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, set target audience to specific view in the SharePoint list modern experience is not available.

Comment: Yes, but are there any ways where I can restrict access per specific view aside from Target Audience in WebParts?  

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Sorry for that there are no other options to achieve this.

Comment: Regardless, thank you so much for your response.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is **No** way to use target Audience in SharePoint Modern experience List view web part.

---

If you are using modern **team** site in SharePoint, try below workaround & see if it works for you (**not guaranteed**).

**Workaround**:

1. Go to your SharePoint list.
2. Click on **Return to classic SharePoint** (You can find it below left side navigation - bottom left corner of the page).
3. Click on **Settings** (Gear icon) --> **Edit page**.
4. Then select the list web part & then **Edit Web Part**.
5. In web part properties panel, expand **Advanced** section, it is on the most right corner of the page next to the list (you may need to scroll horizontally, as shown below).
6. Inside **Target Audiences** add your administrators group (admini_folder).
7. Click **OK**.
8. Click on **PAGE** from top ribbon --> Select **Stop Editing**.
9. Click on **Exit classic experience** (You can find it below left side navigation - bottom left corner of the page).

This only works for groups, so you need to add your user to a group.

[image]
**References**:

1. Check **Target web parts to an audience** at: [How does Audience Targeting in a List / Document Library work?](http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-does-audience-targeting-in-a-list-document-library-work/)
2. Check **Web Parts** topic on Page 4 at: [Audience Targeting in SharePoint](https://www.combined-knowledge.com/documents/knowledgebase/Audience%20Targeting%20in%20SharePoint.pdf).

Comment: But when you convert back , Target audience that you set will not work.

Comment: Yes, I tried your suggestion but not working when reverted to Modern Experience. But thanks anyway for response.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, audience targeting is not yet supported in modern experience. Above workaround worked for me in the past (1-2 years back), I will check if it works now.

Answer (score 0):

List settings, Advanced settings, Classic experience (last setting on the Advanced page).  Believe this forces the classic view and thus the audience targeting.  In any case did not see the “Exit classic view” after changing the setting.